# How to change the badge of a view controller that isn't loaded?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, badge

I have a tab bar controller, that has 3 view controller attached.

Say you start up the app, the first view controller is the only view out of the other three that is loaded. I want set the badge value of the third view controller that isn't loaded. This is because I want the user to know they have notifications when they open the app.

Is it possible and how can I do it? I have tried the following:

Calling the view ( the one that I want to change its badge ) from another class:

```
 NotificationsViewController *class = [NotificationsViewController alloc]init]; 

[class view];
```

Then, In the NotificationsViewController class, I set the badge to 1 if the app has any notifications using parse:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
if (currentInstallation.badge > 0) {

    NSString *badge = @"1";

        [self.tabBarItem setBadgeValue:badge];


    }
   }
```

Why isn't this working? How can I change the badge of the view controller that isn't loaded yet?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of your controller and setting the badge on it.  You need to access the one that's in your tab bar controller.

Comment: @dan could you please provide me some sample code for that? I'm truly lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to get your tab bar item:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:YOUR_INDEX] tabBarItem];
```

Then, simply set the badge on it.

```
NSString *badge = @"1";
[tabBarItem setBadgeValue:badge];
```

Comment: Does the view have to be loaded first?

Comment: No absolutely not, the tabbar item is not directly related to a view, you can always grad the tabbar item and set a badge to it without loading the viewcontroller.

Comment: Hmm Because I get a error relating to the `self.tabBarController`, as I am calling this code from my app delegate? Do I need to change this code if I want to call it from my app delegate?

Comment: So you have a tabbar controller that you're surely initializing in your appdelegate. You only need to call that controller. How are you initializing your tabbar controller?

Comment: This is the code I call: `TabBarViewController *class = [[TabBarViewController alloc]init];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[class.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2] tabBarItem];
    NSString *badge = @"1";
    [tabBarItem setBadgeValue:badge];`

Comment: Are your creating a new instance of your tabbar controller there? You need to grab the tabbar that is shown in your app, not a new one. Please post the code where you populate the tabbar controller.

Comment: I have no idea if I am creating a new instance, thats all the code I use to try change the badge value? I did create a custom class for the tab bar controller but I didn't alter it at all???

Comment: In your AppDelegate has to be a part of code where you initiate your tabbarcontroller, could you please show that part?

Comment: Could you provide example code for what you are talking about? As I use a storyboard Tab Bar Controller, I don't believe you need to do any coding or initialisation to get a tab bar controller working, so I am lost at what you are talking about? This should be so simple yet it is proving to be extremely ambiguous as to why it isn't working?!